# C# How to iterate through table rows and only add certain field names and values to SortedList

Tags: c#

I have a table like so...

```
FACILTY_NAME    FACILITYID  FIELDID MUSYM   MUKEY   SlopeMidPoint   MLRA_ID Shape_Area  MLRASYM FIPS_C
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1839    1698712 6   22  34578.52926120000   72  08 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1815    1698708 0   22  315937.13060200000  72  9 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1650    1698692 0   22  232183.66600100000  72  10 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   5101    1698651 2   22  530405.24224000000  72  11 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1506    1698655 6   22  94914.03552020000   72  12 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1816    1698709 2   22  1036.37023796000    72  13 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   5100    1698650 0   22  532206.08141000000  72  14 56 20 31
JMB Feeders 3557    18894   1736    1698707 6   22  7.45379122495   72  15 56 20 31
```

I only need to grab certain Fields/Values from each row (`Shape_Area`, `SlopeMidPoint`, and `MUKEY`).  My question is: how can I add each of these field values to a `SortedList`?  I have looked at the `SortedList` class and it appears to me that you can only have two elements (Key, Value).  How can I store three elements?  Or, should I be looking at another class like a `List` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: Basic answer is you use define a struct to hold the values you are interested in. This is screaming Linq though, but do you need a SortedList instance, or do you simply want a list in key order?

Comment: I think I need a SortedList (or something of a sorted class) as I need to sort by Shape_Area and SlopeMidPoint.  Basically, I need to to grab the MUKEY of the largest area. I then also need to grab the MUKEY of the row with an area over 30% of the total area with the largest SlopeMidPoint.  Then, I'll need to grab the MUKEY of all the rest.  So, from the table above, there will be one "Dominant" soil (largest area), one "Critical" soil (anything over 30% of total area that has the greatest slope), and multiple "Minor" soils (the remaining).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a `SortedList`?  That will give you a key/value pair as you mentioned.  You could just generate a class that maps to your data structure.

```
class Facility
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    //etc, etc
}
```

Then, when reading your data, whether it is from a database or a flat file, you can simply create a `Facility` object for each row in your data set and add them to a regular `List<Facility>`.

```
List<Facility> facilities = new List<Facility>();

Facility facility = new Facility() { Name = "Foo", Id = 1 /* etc */ };
facilities.Add(facility);
```

You can then use LINQ to get values:

```
var results = yourList.Where(s => s.Id == 3557);
```

Or any other property on your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeClass
{
  string shape_Area {get; set;} 
  string SlopeMidPoint {get; set;}
  string MUKEY  {get; set;}
}
```

SortedList.Add method takes key and value as object, so now you can add SomeClass As the value

like this:

```
sortedList.Add(someClass.MUKEY, someClass);
```

This way you will get a list sorted by MUKEY

Hope this helps...